# Linq group by and select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I have  *.cs model

```
public class TimesheetListModel
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
        public decimal TimeWorked { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have service, that selects my model from database.

Now I need to include my model into List<> new model:

```
 public class TimesheetModel
    {
        public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
        public List<TimesheetListModel> TimesheetList { get; set; }

        public TimesheetModel() { TimesheetList = new List<TimesheetListModel>(); }
    }
```

And I need to select data from db for new model, and group by TaskDate in new model. I have service that realize this query, but it wrote for old model:

```
public IEnumerable<TimesheetListModel> GetTicketsInProgressByUserId(int id)
{
    var query = (from workLogList in DataContext.tblWorkLogs
                 join tickets in DataContext.tblTickets on workLogList.TicketId equals tickets.TicketId
                 join project in DataContext.tblProjects on tickets.ProjectId equals project.ProjectId
                 join states  in DataContext.tblWorkflowStates on tickets.Status equals states.StateId
                 where workLogList.AccountId == id
                 select new TimesheetListModel
                 {
                     ProjectName = project.Name,
                     TaskDate = workLogList.WorkDate,
                     Task = "#" + tickets.TicketId + " : " +  tickets.Title,
                     TimeWorked = workLogList.TimeWorked,
                     Note = workLogList.Note
                 });
    return query.ToList();
}
```

How I need to rewrite my query for selecting data for new model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:-

```
where workLogList.AccountId == id
group workLogList by workLogList.WorkDate into g
select new TimesheetModel
      {
          TaskDate = g.Key,
          TimesheetList = g.ToList()
      });
```

Comment: But how I can add this? 
ProjectName = project.Name, 
TaskDate = workLogList.WorkDate, 
Task = "#" + tickets.TicketId + " : " + tickets.Title, 
TimeWorked = workLogList.TimeWorked, 
Note = workLogList.Note
?

Comment: @HUSTLIN - Here `g` will be an IEnumerable of models which you have joined. You can project it with a select if you want to access different properties like this: `TimesheetList = g.Select(x => new TimesheetList { ProjectName = x.project.Name ... and so on }).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful for me!)